# Why is pcgsolve function not running in R?

Tags: r, function, error-handling, package, r-library

I've installed the package cPCG with succes, yet my computer(s) will not recognise the functin pcgsolve (the peconditioned conjugate gradient method).
Every time I try to use it, it says

`Error in pcgsolve(A) : could not find function "pcgsolve"`

It comes from this R-page which seems like the propper R documentation
http://search.r-project.org/library/cPCG/html/pcgsolve.html

any advice?

Comment: Did you run `library(cPCG)` before calling the function?

Comment: I have now and it works!! thank you!!